# Control duplicate entries with angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, duplicates

I’m using angular.js to get some form data from some input fields. I need to build a feature that prevents a user from entering duplicate fields. So if a user entered duplicate fields I need alert the user with a alert box and than remove the duplicate. I know how to do this with jQuery, look at the code below. What is the most efficient way to achieve this with angular.js? Any help is greatly appreciated, I have template fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/1013/) to make it easier.

```
/** Handle Duplicate Barcodes **/
  $(".alldifferent").on('keyup paste',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    keyupDelay(function() {
      var val = $this.val();
      $this.attr('value', val);
      if (val != '') {
        var $dupes = $('input[value="' + val + '"]:gt(0)').val('');
        if ($dupes.length > 0) alert('Error: Duplicates barcodes are not allowed!');
      }
    }, 300);
  });

  var keyupDelay = (function() {
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();
```

Comment: check for dupes on ng-change

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/1014/

Comment: @juvian, this example is very close.. I need to remove the duplicate after it alerts the user.. is that possible?

Comment: You could but its highly inconvenient, if one of the inputs has a 'a', you can no loger make a word starting with a on any other input. You can set either $scope.entries[i] or [j] to '' if you want

Comment: Maybe preventing duplicates like this is better: http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/1015/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ng-blur` as a blur event fires when an element has lost focus.

If you can know the index at which the duplicate entry is being entered you can filter that item in the array and clear it.

```
$scope.check = function(val, index){
  if(val !== '') {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.num.length; i++ ){
       var itm = $scope.num[i].text;
       if(itm == val && i != index) {
         $scope.num[index].text = '';
         alert('Error: Duplicates barcodes are not allowed!');
         break;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aP6Q5zYfJr1dav02Eq0L?p=preview)